# Where Clause In CAML Query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I want to return all info for a specified user. The internal field name is UserAssigned. If I use this

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
{
  Console.WriteLine(listItem[“UserAssigned”]);
}
```

I get `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue` returned. How can I translate that to either set my CAML query to return everything for ID 31836 OR username Jones, Jack?

This is C# and CSOM

**EDIT**
This is the syntax I have...

```
string siteURL = "";
var ctx = new ClientContext(siteURL);
var web = ctx.Web;
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListTitle");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "";

var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

ctx.Load(listItemCollection,
         eachItem => eachItem.Include(
                     item => item,
                     item => item["ID"],
                     item => item["UserAssigned"]
                     ));

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(listItem["ID"];
    FieldUserValue un = (FieldUserValue)listItem["UserAssigned"];
    string unGood = un.LookupValue;
    Console.WriteLine(unGood);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Edit 2**
I edited my syntax to be the below - but it is ignoring my where clause...

```
User user = ctx.Web.CurrentUser;
ctx.Load(user);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
string itsme = user.Title;

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UserAssigned' /><value Type='User'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>", itsme);
var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

ctx.Load(listItemCollection, 
         eachItem => eachItem.Include(
                 item => item,
                 item => item["ID"],
                 item => item["UserAssigned"]
                 ));

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
{
  Console.WriteLine(listItem["ID"];
  FieldUserValue un = (FieldUserValue)listItem["UserAssigned"];
  string unGood = un.LookupValue;
  Console.WriteLine(unGood);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the display name of the user from the `listItem["UserAssigned"]`

```
FieldUserValue user = (FieldUserValue)listItem["UserAssigned"];
string name = user.LookupValue; //display name
```

CAML query by this user

```
string query=string.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UserAssigned'/><Value Type='User'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", name );
```

**Edit**

to get the current logged in user

```
User user = ctx.Web.CurrentUser;    
ctx.Load(user);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
string name = user.Title;
```

You can query one time using the current logged in user using the above CAML query

Comment: see my edit - that shows how to parse out the required info AFTER a CamlQuery has been executed.  So would I then need to run a second CamlQuery to get the exclusive data for the username I am after?  Ore am I missing the obvious here?

Comment: @user2676140 will the first part of my answer is getting the user info , which you already did, the second part of my answer showing how to query using user's name  (string name) in the CAML query

Comment: If I understand correctly, then I would then need to add in a second CamlQuery to then exclusively pull the data for the UserAssigned?

Comment: I am wanting to only pull all records for ONE user - would I have to 1) Query all records to get unique names, then 2) Query sharepoint again to query against one name?

Comment: @user2676140 this one user is suppose to be the current user?  meaning you need to show the user only his records?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am attempting to accomplish!

Comment: @user2676140 i edited my answer and you can get the current logged in user and query the list for the user's records only one time

Comment: Trying the edited syntax I get compile error of 'User' does not contain a definition for 'LookupValue' and no extension method 'LookupValue' accepting a first argument of type 'User' could be found

Comment: @user2676140 yep , my mistake check the edit user.LoginName; or user.Title

Comment: I get debug error of The property or field 'LoginName' has not been initialized.  It has not been requested or the request has not been executed.  It may need to be explicitly requested

Comment: @user2676140 you should load the user first ,pls check the edit

Comment: That will return Domain Credentials which differs from the SharePoint credentials.  Should I just use a switch statement to map the SharePoint creds to the Domain creds?

Comment: @user2676140 user.Title; will return the name user.LoginName; will return cred used in log in to sharepoint

Comment: Perfect - that got it!  Thank you for working with me on othis!

Comment: So how would I then write the CAML Query since my field UserAssigned only returns Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue

Comment: @user2676140 welcome :), i already added the CAML where clause querying using the name string object

Comment: See my edit - the result set returned seems to be ignoring my where clause

Comment: @user2676140 add <View><Query> tags and try again

Comment: Adding in the <View> and <Query> tags now throws a debug error of Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ServerException: Value does not fall within the expected range

Answer (score 1):

You do your query call before you pull the list items.  Once you have your query then you get your list items based off of that.

Example below:

```
using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        //Get your item by ID then pull what you want after.  This query returns a single list item from your ID
        query.ViewXml = string.Concat("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldName Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>31836</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>");

        string listUrl = spWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/YourList";
        SPList list = spWeb.GetList(listUrl);
        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

        foreach(SPListItem item in items) {
            //here is your stuff for that user (List Item)
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for.  Hope this helps.

Comment: User assigned.ID = 31836 and userassigned.name = Jones, Jack. Unless I parse out the data I get my error described above. How can I at the CAML query portion extract out the value for name or id to use in my query?  If I attempt the sample you suggest above, no results are returned bc it always evaluated to false.

Comment: paste your code.  I do not think you understand what this function is doing.  This is a SPOM replacement which uses your id and will retrun a single result.  This code works.

Comment: I am mobile atm, but will post my code soon. I do not want a single result returned. I am after all data belonging to a specific userID or username.

Comment: I think I missunderstood the question.  I do that sometimes.  Someone below me posted something that look at.